# ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code) - OpenLLM

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, langchain

After pip install openllm , when trying to access openllm, getting the below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPMnm.png)

My python version is : 3.11.x

Comment: Don't post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stated on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/openllm/) that it's highly recommended to use a [Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to prevent package conflicts.

You don't appear to be using one yet.